# Change Letters in URL Before Redirect

Tags: php

I'm trying to grab the current pages URL and change some values in it before redirecting to the next page with `header()`

If my current url is `http://example.com/abc-def-1-xxx-g.php` I want to change the `xxx` part to `a` so my url will then be `http://example.com/abc-def-1-a-g.php`

**Heres what I have for the header on the xxx page before redirect**

```
header("Location: whattoputhere.php?". $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
```

Comment: Is the `xxx` a unique string in the url and you want only to change it in one location to `a` ?

Comment: @Rizier123 it will always be the same in the url, so it can always be `xxx` and i always want to change it to `a`

Comment: Then i hope my answer can help you

Comment: BTW, why do you want to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
$str = "http://example.com/abc-def-1-xxx-g.php";
$url = str_replace("xxx", "a", $str);

//For example
echo $url;
```

Output:

```
http://example.com/abc-def-1-a-g.php
```

**EDIT:**

To grab the current URL use this:

```
$str = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
```

Also don't forget to use `exit()` after each header so you are sure the script stops to be executed like this:

```
header("Location: $url");
exit();
```

Comment: how do i define $str from the current url? that part i want to be dynamic since i just want it to grab the current url instead of me having to define it

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$actual_link = "http://".$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST].$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI];
$url = str_replace("xxx", "a", $actual_link); 
Header("Location: ".$url);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily parse the string before you call header().

Try parse_str, str_replace, etc.

And you have both $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] and $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] available, depending on which you need to parse:

```
$qs = parse_str(str_replace("$string_I_do_not_want",'',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));

if ($some_value_from_string == $something_to_change) {

    $new_value = compute_my_new_value();
}
$new_location = "http://example.com/". $somepage . $my_qs_with_new_value;
header("location: $new_location");
exit;
```